# How to bind the values to v-model in Custom Directive?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am creating a common custom directive(icheck).
Trying to pull the vmodel and bind the data to it.
http://embed.plnkr.co/4WNrzF/

The problem now is if

```
//html
<input type="checkbox" v-model="form.answer"> Something1
<input type="checkbox" v-model="form.answer"> Something2

//main.js
new Vue({
  data:{
     form:{
       answer:""
     }       
  },
  directive:{
    icheck
  }
});


//directive.js
Vue.directive("icheck",{
  inserted:function(el,b,vnode){

  jQuery(el).iCheck({
    checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-green',
    radioClass: 'iradio_square-green',
    increaseArea: '20%' // optional
  });

  jQuery(el).on('ifChanged', function(e){

    if($(el).attr("type") == "checkbox") {           

        //how do I bind the data            
    }
 });
}
```

Comment: No, I am trying to insert the new value to the v-model ie form.answer
I know that I can access it through vNode.context[vnode.data.directives] but my v-model is "form.answer" which gives me error when I try to do vNode.context["vNode.context"]

Comment: could you let me know the reason for not using vue-cli?